# uninitialized constant PurchasesController::UserMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I've generated a mailer for an Order confirmation. I'm getting a NameError at /purchases.
The error reads:

```
uninitialized constant PurchasesController::UserMailer
  /controllers/purchases_controller.rb

 class PurchasesController < InheritedResources::Base
   before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!, :only => [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]

   def create
     @purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchase])
     if @purchase.save
       UserMailer.purchase_confirmation(@purchase).deliver
       redirect_to "/thankyou"
     else     
       render :action => "new"
     end
```

I've been digging around and have found similar issues, but nothing as of yet to solve my problem. Any help?

Comment: are you sure you have a mailer called UserMailer?

Comment: show your UserMailer model

Comment: @jvnill - Brilliant. Well that fixed that. Now I'm getting an Undefined method for mailto: purchase.email

Answer (score -1):

It may be cause by two problems and the following is just an Idea...

`1)` You need to restart the `rails server` after you added the `Mailer`

(or)

Try to run in your `production` server and check it.

`2)` check the spell of `UserMailer` should be `user_mailer.rb`

(or)

Make sure that you are using `UserMailer`. 
 `UserMailer.rb` will break whereas `user_mailer.rb` is what is expected.

Let us know once its not solved the above two options

Comment: asking someone to test code by running it on their production server is *not cool*.

Comment: I had the same problem and when I starting `RAILS_ENV=production ./script/server` and error dissapear. Is that wrong to convey this message to him to check it or not?

Comment: Hey thanks for the ideas @sri - but I did fix that errror, but now getting another one. But I do agree with sevensseacat - I'm glad I didnt try it in prodcuction. haha.

Comment: @RussellKompinski do you have `email` in your model.. if not add `attr_accessible: email` in your model and check it..

Comment: @sri i do have it in my model but im still getting undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Here are the details laid out in another post @sri - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117120/nomethoderror-for-email-in-actionmailer